# Data protection key ring with S3 not working properly in dot net core

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, data-protection

We are using MVC with dotnet core 2.2.0 version. For data protection we are using AWS S3 as persistent  storage. Web app is hosted as windows service on two machines behind the load balancer. Authentication is based on cookies. On both machines we have below configuration for store key ring on S3.

```
    "AwsProfile": true,
    "Location": "s3-bucket-name",
    "UseS3Protection": true,
    "KeyPrefix": "keys/", 
    "CanMachineGenerateKeyRing" : true
```

CanMachineGenerateKeyRing is true on both machines. Code sample for adding data protection is as below:

```
       services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName("app") 
      .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(10))
      .PersistKeysToAwsS3(CreateAmazonS3Client(configuration), 
      .new S3XmlRepositoryConfig(configuration["Location"]) 
      { 
         KeyPrefix = configuration["KeyPrefix"] 
      })
     .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(certificate1)
     .UnprotectKeysWithAnyCertificate(certificate1);
```

After adding the data protection layer we added the cookies authentication layer as below:

```
       services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
       .AddCookie(options =>
       {
           options.Cookie.Name = "cookie1";
           options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
           options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("app");
           options.DataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("app");
           options.Cookie.Path = "/";
           options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
           options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
           options.ExpireTimeSpan =
                       TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
           options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
           options.LoginPath = "/login";               
           options.Validate();
       });
```

Now, problem is that : after user authentication successfully, authentication cookie landed on browser. Whenever I request server for protected resource, some request processed successfully and some of them getting failed with status 403. When i see logs, Its say

> Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"{AuthenticationScheme} was not authenticated. Failure message: {FailureMessage}","Properties":{"AuthenticationScheme":"Cookies","FailureMessage":"Unprotect ticket failed","EventId":{"Id":7},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
>
> {"Timestamp":"2020-01-24T20:14:10.6128310+00:00","Level":"Warning","MessageTemplate":"Error unprotecting the session cookie.","Exception":"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {d21e65c4-b7f0-41dd-903b-ab11f4a788d0} was not found in the key ring.\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)

One strange behavior is that cookie is unprotected by only one machine who created it.
Please help, I don't know what is the exact error.

Comment: Removing  options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("app");
                  options.DataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("app"); from AddCookie method resolved problem. More info https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18572#issuecomment-580313791

Comment: So you just removed data protection for your cookies?  That's not really solving a problem, it's just removing the cause.  Do you use data protection on any other data in your app?  If not, then you can remove the services.AddDataProtection() too.